# Connecting to two diffrent data bases using Pro* C code

Tags: database, database-connection, proc, openvms

how can we connect to two different databases using Pro* C code. I have entries in tnsnames.ora file. By default it is connection to one of the Databases using EXEC SQL CONNECT statement which I am not sure how it is connecting. I want to connect to another DB which is having an entry in tnsnames.ora file. I am using OpenVMS OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vijay Kumar

Below outlines what I have done in the pass to accomplish this.

**Default connection**

If you do not have a CONNECT statement in your code, Oracle will perform an auto connect when it encounters the first SQL statement.  It uses credential information configure by the person who setup the database.

**Multiple connections**

To connect to multiple databases in Pro C, you must make an explicit connection to all databases reference by the code.

Outline below are the 3 steps I done in the pass to accomplish this:

- Declare a database alias name.  This will be used to reference the
  connection.
- Explicitly connect to the database and assigned the alias to the connection.  This is done by including an AT clause in the CONNECT statement.
- In following SQL statements, reference the connection by including an AT clause.

**Example code:**

```
/*
 * Declare the database aliases
 */ 
EXEC SQL DECLARE DB1 DATABASE;
EXEC SQL DECLARE DB2 DATABASE;


/*
 * Explicitly connect to the database.  Include an AT clause to name the connection
 */ 
EXEC SQL CONNECT :db1_uid IDENTIFIED BY :db1_pwd
         AT DB1;
EXEC SQL CONNECT :db2_uid IDENTIFIED BY :db2_pwd
         AT DB2;


/*
 * In the SQL statements, reference the connection by including the AT clause.
 */ 
EXEC SQL AT DB1 SELECT COL1 INTO :var1
         FROM TABLE_1
         WHERE COL2 = 'some_value';

EXEC SQL AT DB2 SELECT COLUMN1 INTO :var2
         FROM TABLE_2
         WHERE COLUMN2 = 'some_value';

EXEC SQL AT DB1 COMMIT WORK RELEASE;
EXEC SQL AT DB2 COMMIT WORK RELEASE;
```

**Things to note:**

- DB1 and DB2 are programmer define alias names.
- Passwords, represented by the variables db1_pwd and db2_pwd, must be
  variables and not hard coded values.
- The username value, stored in variables db1_uid and db1_uid2, was in the following format: username@DatabaseName

Note I believe there are other methods for accomplish this.  This is the method I was successful in getting to work.

You can find more information on connecting to databases in the [Oracle Pro *C/C++ Programmer’s Guide.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10825/pc_03dbc.htm#i5880)